# Python return corresponding cell with time data between 2 values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Currently I am in the process of writing some software to do data analysis. I have had a little issue with my code and now some of the data is corrupted with wrong time values. I would like python to find the rows of data where the time value is between 00:00:00 and 03:59:00 and return to me the corresponding 'Ticker' and 'Exchange' value from the same row, but unfortunately I am having issues accomplishing this and was hoping someone on here could help me out.

Example data frame:

```
   Ticker Exchange      Date      Time
0    AAPL   NASDAQ  20200501  01:00:00
1    AAPL   NASDAQ  20200501  02:00:00
2    AAPL   NASDAQ  20200501  03:00:00
3    AAPL   NASDAQ  20200502  01:00:00
4    AAPL   NASDAQ  20200502  02:00:00
5    AAPL   NASDAQ  20200502  03:00:00
6    TSLA   NASDAQ  20200501  05:00:00
7    TSLA   NASDAQ  20200501  06:00:00
8    TSLA   NASDAQ  20200501  07:00:00
9    TSLA   NASDAQ  20200502  05:00:00
10   TSLA   NASDAQ  20200502  06:00:00
11   TSLA   NASDAQ  20200502  07:00:00
```

Example output:

```
  Ticker Exchange
0   AAPL   NASDAQ
```

In this case, 'AAPL' stock from 'NASDAQ' exchange has time values between 00:00:00 and 03:59:00 and therefore python should return to me the ticker and the exchange.

I hope I was able to make myself clear and that someone on here can help me out.

Example code for copy paste:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Ticker': ['AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL','TSLA', 'TSLA', 'TSLA', 'TSLA', 'TSLA', 'TSLA'],
                'Exchange': ['NASDAQ','NASDAQ','NASDAQ','NASDAQ','NASDAQ','NASDAQ','NASDAQ','NASDAQ','NASDAQ','NASDAQ','NASDAQ','NASDAQ'],
                'Date': [20200501, 20200501, 20200501, 20200502, 20200502, 20200502, 20200501, 20200501, 20200501, 20200502, 20200502, 20200502],
                'Time': ['01:00:00','02:00:00','03:00:00','01:00:00','02:00:00','03:00:00','05:00:00','06:00:00','07:00:00','05:00:00','06:00:00','07:00:00',]})
print(df1)

output = pd.DataFrame({'Ticker': ['AAPL'],
                'Exchange': ['NASDAQ']})

print(output)


#Code from MaKaNu that results in error: "TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [int32]"

minimal = pd.DataFrame({'time': [pd.to_datetime('00:00:00')]})
maximal = pd.DataFrame({'time': [pd.to_datetime('03:59:00')]})

#The lines below give the error
minimal = pd.to_datetime(minimal['time']).astype(int) / 10**9
maximal = pd.to_datetime(maximal['time']).astype(int) / 10**9

df_unix_sec = pd.to_datetime(df1['Time']).astype(int) / 10**9

series = df_unix_sec.between(minimal[0], maximal[0])
result = df1.loc[series == True][['Ticker', 'Exchange']].loc[0]
print(result)
```

Comment: Is your only condition that the time needs to be between 0:00:00 and 3:59:00?

Comment: Thank you for your response @MaKaNu . Yes, my only criteria is that the row needs to contain data between 00:00:00 and 03:59:00. It doesn't have to be every minute, 1 row between this timeframe is already corrupted data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To look between your two conditions you first step is to create number values out of your string. To be continous I created two small dataframe with just the min and the max values

```py
minimal = pd.DataFrame({'time': [pd.to_datetime('0:00:00')]})
maximal = pd.DataFrame({'time': [pd.to_datetime('3:59:00')]})
```

than used the function `pd.to_datetime` and set it as integer and devided by 10 to the power 9 to create reasonable values.

```py
minimal = pd.to_datetime(minimal['time']).astype(int) / 10**9
maximal = pd.to_datetime(maximal['time']).astype(int) / 10**9
```

Next step is to do the same with the column `'Time'` in the original dataframe.

```py
df_unix_sec = pd.to_datetime(df1['Time']).astype(int) / 10**9
```

As a last step I used the built-in function `between` and used the first entry from `minimal` and `maximal` as arguments.

```py
print(df_unix_sec.between(minimal[0], maximal[0]))
```

The Result which I printed is a pandas series with Boolean values:

```sh
0      True
1      True
2      True
3      True
4      True
5      True
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
11    False
Name: Time, dtype: bool
```

As you can see all the values between your condition are True.

Now we just save this series and use them as a mask for our original dataframe.

```py
series = df_unix_sec.between(minimal[0], maximal[0])
print(df1.loc[series == True])
```

The result looks like this:

```sh
  Ticker Exchange      Date      Time
0   AAPL   NASDAQ  20200501  01:00:00
1   AAPL   NASDAQ  20200501  02:00:00
2   AAPL   NASDAQ  20200501  03:00:00
3   AAPL   NASDAQ  20200502  01:00:00
4   AAPL   NASDAQ  20200502  02:00:00
5   AAPL   NASDAQ  20200502  03:00:00
```

And if you just need the example outpout from your question:

```py
result = df1.loc[series == True][['Ticker', 'Exchange']].loc[0]
print(result)
```

Result:

```sh
Ticker        AAPL
Exchange    NASDAQ
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @MaKaNu . I can see where this is going. Unfortunately I am receiving an error: "TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [int32]" in the row where you try to convert the datetime to an integer value. I have been trying to fix this but so far not succesfull. Can you help me out here please?

Comment: I completly worked with your example code. Did you used the function ```pd.to_datetime```?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, i 100% copy pasted your code. I have tried a few things, like converting it to int in a new line, with "unit='s", and some others, but I keep getting this error code unfortunately.

Comment: Could you edit your Question an Include the code, which results in the error?

Comment: Yes, no problem. I just did it

Comment: In my test environment everything works well. I used this online env: https://paiza.io/en/projects/new?language=python3
Python Version: 3.8.2
Pandas Version: 1.1.2
Please compare it with your Install environment. To print Versions:
```import sys, pandas; print (sys.version); print(pandas.__version__)```

Comment: I have a different version of python (3.7). I accepted your answer since it works on the most up to date version of python and it does show me how to fix my issue, ill work on the other part when I have time. Thank you!